# WSAWaitForMultipleEvents returns successfully, but WSANETWORKEVENTS object is empty

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

This code compiles and runs. When the client connects, the WSAWaitForMultipleEvents returns with nReturnCode = 0 (which equals WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0). But the code always displays "EVENT: NOT ACCEPT" and when I look at NetworkEvents in debug mode, it is completely filled with zeroes.

I didn't expect this code to work because I don't really know how to initialize the variable NetworkEvents. Don't I have to somehow "bind" it to the socket ? How is the struct supposed to know that it should store the network events of ListenSocket ?

```
    WSAEVENT event = WSACreateEvent();
    WSAEventSelect(ListenSocket, event, FD_CONNECT | FD_ACCEPT | FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);
    //DWORD cEvents = MAKELONG(MAKEWORD(0, 0), MAKEWORD(0, 1));
    WSAEVENT lphEvents[1] = {event};
    //lphEvents[0] = event;
    //DWORD dwTimeout = MAKELONG(MAKEWORD(0, 0), MAKEWORD(0, 0));
    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents = {0};
    int nReturnCode = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &lphEvents[0], false, WSA_INFINITE, false);

    if ((NetworkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT) == FD_ACCEPT) {
        std::cout << "EVENT: ACCEPT !" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "EVENT: NOT ACCEPT !" << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set everything to 0 at `WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents = {0};` and there's no code elsewhere that uses that variable, so it's going to be zeroes when you check that structure.

You're probably missing a call to  `WSAEnumNetworkEvents` after `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`

```
if (WSAEnumNetworkEvents(ListenSocket, event, &NetworkEvents) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("WSAEnumNetworkEvents() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: That was the answer. Thank you !

Comment: Can WSANETWORKEVENTS::lNetworkEvents contain multiple events?